# CSS Stylesheet not update on server

Tags: css, laravel

I use laravel 5 and I have uploaded it on a server

I have changed the style.css in public / assets / css folder,But i can't see update in my website .. what's wrong dude?

Comment: Try clearing your laravel cache https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache

Comment: u try incognito mode? did still not change?

Comment: Check if the edit or upload of your modified css files was really successful. Try "ctrl+ f5" or clear your browsercache.

Comment: I have done it many times, But still no change

Answer (score 1):

I think Browser Caching is enabled on your server so first check if the file is uploaded properly and then do Ctrl + F5 for 3-4 times. if it still not loading new then go to view source and then click on that css link and then do Ctrl+f4 3-4 times.
Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: php artisan view:clear and php artisan cache clear looks cool.